# jquery filer not giving error for maximum size when selecting files one by one

Tags: jquery

I am using [jQuery.filer](http://filer.grandesign.md/) for uploading multiple images at once.  When more than one file is selected at a time, I calculate the total size and display an error if it's greater than the maximum upload size.  However, if only one file is selected, it's not checking the maximum allowed upload size.

Comment: library name is jquery.filer. i am not able to give name in tags due to my low reputation.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: $('.file_input').filer({                                                                     showThumbs: true,
 maxSize:5,                                                                                                       });  while maxSize is for calculating total size when i select more than one file at once

Comment: its fixed. i calculated and add size of file each time and compare that total size with maxSize.